# Check if file is locked using cmdline and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to determine if file is locked using CmdLine and VBA.

I want to run the check and return the output to file. 
I cannot use .Exec because I want to run it in silent mode.

When executing the file isn't created, but if I run this exact command manually it works.

Can someone tell me what's wrong here? I still want to use CmdLine.

```
Function IsFileLocked(sFilePath)

Set oWScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sOutput = oWScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%") & "\file.txt"

sCommand = "cmd /c """ & "2>nul ( >>" & sFilePath & " (call) ) && (echo False) || (echo True)"" > " & sOutput & """"

oWScriptShell.Run sCommand, 0, True

End Function
```

Comment: VBA? Which Microsoft Office application are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, Excel.

Comment: You say VBA here and VBS in the comment to Andreas' answer. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function IsWorkBookOpen which returns if a file is open or not with boolean result (true/false)

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

I'm quite sure I found the code on Microsoft but I can't find the link now.

Comment: I need to use it in VBS script and do not want to use any On Error statement.

Comment: Your question states VBA.

Comment: Either way, it doesn't work in VBA and I don't want to use this kind of handling.

Comment: It does work. I use it every day. If you have specific requrements about your code then those should be listed in the question